# Why does Excel VBA editor change line continuation word wrapping?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code in Excel VBA that is long, and I want to use a line continuation to break it into two lines. However, after I move the cursor away from that line of code, the editor changes my preferred word wrapping. How do I make it stop doing that?

```
If IsEmpty([Task].Cells(rowNo, [Task[SchedDateTime]].Column)) And _
   IsEmpty([Task].Cells(rowNo, [Task[DaysAlloc]].Column)) Then
```

gets changed by the editor to:

```
If IsEmpty([Task].Cells(rowNo, [Task[SchedDateTime]].Column)) And IsEmpty( _
   [Task].Cells(rowNo, [Task[DaysAlloc]].Column)) Then
```

which I think is harder to read.

Comment: Why are you using bracketed identifiers? What is `Task`?

Comment: Did you use both space and linebreak after underscore?

Comment: @Phanti the line continuation token is defined as whitespace+underscore+linebreak. The problem is caused by the bracketed identifiers, not the line continuation.

Answer (score 5):

Stop using bracketed identifiers. This trick is good for throw-away code and quick debugger stuff in the immediate pane, not for actual production code.

When you do `[Task]`, you're stepping out of VBA land and defer to the host application - Excel - which will do `Application.Evaluate("Task")` and, presumably, get a `Range` object back.

From the looks of your code, it sounds like `Task` is the name of some table. Why not be explicit about where that table is coming from, instead of making Excel work it out?

```
Dim taskTable As ListObject
Set taskTable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Task")
```

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you could then leverage the powerful `ListObject` API instead of working with late-bound implicit code half resolved by Excel and half resolved by VBA.

```
Dim scheduleTimestampColumn As Long
scheduleTimestampColumn = taskTable.ListColumns("SchedDateTime").Index

Dim daysAllocColumn As Long
daysAllocColumn = taskTable.ListColumns("DaysAlloc").Index

Dim currentRow As ListRow
For Each currentRow In taskTable.ListRows
    If IsEmpty(currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=scheduleTimestampColumn).Value) And _
       IsEmpty(currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=daysAllocColumn).Value) _
    Then
       '...do stuff...
    End If
Next
```

VBA supports bracketed expressions as a shorthand surrogate for `Application.Evaluate` (or `Worksheet.Evaluate`, depending on context... so, it's actually even more implicit than I wrote near the top of this answer). It also supports bracketed identifiers, in certain contexts, for names that can have whitespace in them, or otherwise make illegal VBA identifiers.

But `[TableName[ColumnName]]` is completely Excel-land (table formula notation) - VBA has no idea what that means, and the square brackets *inside* the bracketed expression are thoroughly confusing it. Without the nested brackets, the VBE doesn't get confused and doesn't wreck your indent. But without bracketed expressions, you get a not-confused VBE *and* explicit code that says what it does, and does what it says - *plus* compile-time validation for everything!